# Mosquitto 2.0.15 Websocket

Tags: windows, mosquitto

I am using Mosquitto 2.0.15 on Windows 11 with two identical machines (same hardware and software).

The Mosquitto config as follows works without issue on the first machine:

```
allow_anonymous true

listener 1883 0.0.0.0

listener 8883 0.0.0.0
protocol mqtt
cafile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt
certfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\server.crt
keyfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\server.key
tls_version tlsv1.2

listener 9001 0.0.0.0
protocol websockets
cafile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\ca.crt
certfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\server.crt
keyfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\server.key
tls_version tlsv1.2

log_type all
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
connection_messages true
```

I only have `allow_anonymous` as true for testing purposes. Otherwise it uses username/password auth.

On the first machine running it in the console shows the following:

```
mosquitto -c 'C:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf' -v
2023-12-06T15:41:22: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
2023-12-06T15:41:22: Config loaded from C:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf.
2023-12-06T15:41:22: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
2023-12-06T15:41:22: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
2023-12-06T15:41:22: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
2023-12-06T15:41:22: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

I can then check the port with `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 9001` and it shows the `State` as `Listen` as expected.  Same goes for port 1883 and 8883.

However that same Mosquitto config on the second machine shows the same Mosquitto console log output about binding to the 3 ports, but when running `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 9001` it shows nothing on that port, but does if I check 1883 and 8883.  I have checked and no app is using port 9001 and I have even changed ports for websockets with the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After additional troubleshooting I added `websockets_log_level 1023` to the mosquitto.conf and now I can see it complaining about binding to the port.

```
2023-12-07T15:16:09: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
2023-12-07T15:16:09: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
2023-12-07T15:16:09: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
2023-12-07T15:16:09: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
2023-12-07T15:16:09: ERROR on binding fd 568 to port 9001 (-1 10047)
2023-12-07T15:16:09: VH default: iface 0.0.0.0 port 9001 DOESN'T EXIST
```

Still nothing on that port in use.

Comment: Is the failing machine on a network that supports IPv6?

Comment: Also does it work if you remove the `0.0.0.0` from all the listener lines, as that should give the same behaviour.